# Connecting Android app to Django web server's Postgresql on Heroku

Tags: android, django, postgresql, heroku

I have deployed a web server on heroku based on django framework and connected to heroku's postgresql. Now I am building an android application that authenticates data from server for instance there is a login form. On searching I have found that making a HTTP request by android can work but it is a bit unclear to me still. I have following queries in mind.

1. I am using auth users in my web app and built in login functionality so do I have to create a separate django view that accepts HTTP request and respond accordingly? If yes how do I authenticate?
2. The android should make a post request? passing username and password?

I am new in android so don't know much about it. Kindly guide me what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the Django Rest Framework 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/
to have your Android App communicate with your Django backend through its powerful API.

In the link provided, there is also a tutorial about authentication.
I hope that gets you started.

Comment: Thanks that did the work. I have added REST API, hopefully I'll get android app to get information through it. :)